# Reorganise data present in two columns so that columns are items in first column and rows are items in column 2 if grouped with item in first column

Tags: google-sheets, unique, transpose, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have data such as following

```
A 1
B 2
A 3
B 4
A 5
```

I want to get the following

```
A B
1 2
3 4
5
```

A pivot table does not help, it gives me the following

```
  A  B
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

paste in **D1**:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A))
```

paste in **D2** and drag to the right:

```
=QUERY($A1:$B, "select B where A='"&D1&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on what your solution does ?

Comment: @AnkitJain sure... first formula creates row of unique values from column A. then 2nd and 3rd formula use that row as a reference in query and both of them construct a column of values as requested in your question